# Difference between Bayesian inference and Bayesian updating

Tags: bayesian

Bayesian updating and Bayesian inference seem to be often used interchangeably. However, sometimes texts refer to both and seem to mean something different.

Is there a difference between Bayesian inference and updating, and if there is, what is the difference?

Comment: nothing major in using one word or the other...

Comment: Bayesian updating is the process of taking new data & using it to update the posterior distribution while Bayesian inference refers to the methodology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To certain extent the two terms are exchangeable, but, depending on the context, they may refer to different aspects of Bayesian approach.

*Inference* typically means estimating parameters, which in this case may be done, e.g., using the maximum *a posteriori* estimate (MAP estimate) as opposed to the maximum likelihood (ML) in frequentist approach.

*Updating* would imply improving the existing distribution using the new data. Note that though the inference is usually done using all the data at once, the updating may be done sequentially, as the data arrives. In some problems this difference may be quite important.